# Computing Lorenz asymmetry cofficient (S)

Tags: confidence-interval, lorenz-curve

Damgaard and Weiner in [Describing Inequality in Plant Size or Fecundity](http://jacobweiner.dk/Site/Publications_files/Damgaard_Weiner_2000.pdf) discuss computing the Lorenz asymmetry coefficient, S as well as confidence intervals for the estimates of S for a sample.

D A Seekell, P D'Odorico and M L Pace in [Virtual water transfers unlikely to redress inequality in global water use](http://iopscience.iop.org/1748-9326/6/2/024017/fulltext/) also discuss the Lorenz asymmetry coefficient and reference the above article.

I can not find a discussion anywhere on how to specifically compute the confidence intervals for the Lorenz asymmetry coefficient. Spicifically I am looking for:

1) The formulas to compute same.
2) An implementation in open source software that performs the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

There must be several methods. I can think of two at the moment.

1. [Likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) intervals: given that [$S$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_asymmetry_coefficient) is increasing, calculate a likelihood interval of $\mu$ and then transform it into an interval of $S$. This will be a likelihood interval of $S$, by invariance property of the likelihood.
2. [Bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29): Resample (with replacement) and obtain estimators of $S$ using these. Using the sample of estimators, you can calculate Quantile, Bias Corrected, Bias Corrected Accelerated ... confidence intervals. In this case you can use the R package ['boot'](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf).

I don't know of any implementation of this, but they are not too difficult to implement in R.

Best wishes.